# How to do Constrained Linear Regression - scikit learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to carry out linear regression subject using some constraints to get a certain prediction.
I want to make the model predicting half of the linear prediction, and  the last half linear prediction near the last value in the first half using a very narrow range (using constraints) similar to a green line in figure.

The full code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
data = [5.269, 5.346, 5.375, 5.482, 5.519, 5.57, 5.593999999999999, 5.627000000000001, 5.724, 5.818, 5.792999999999999, 5.817, 5.8389999999999995, 5.882000000000001, 5.92, 6.025, 6.064, 6.111000000000001, 6.1160000000000005, 6.138, 6.247000000000001, 6.279, 6.332000000000001, 6.3389999999999995, 6.3420000000000005, 6.412999999999999, 6.442, 6.519, 6.596, 6.603, 6.627999999999999, 6.76, 6.837000000000001, 6.781000000000001, 6.8260000000000005, 6.849, 6.875, 6.982, 7.018, 7.042000000000001, 7.068, 7.091, 7.204, 7.228, 7.261, 7.3420000000000005, 7.414, 7.44, 7.516, 7.542000000000001, 7.627000000000001, 7.667000000000001, 7.821000000000001, 7.792999999999999, 7.756, 7.871, 8.006, 8.078, 7.916, 7.974, 8.074, 8.119, 8.228, 7.976, 8.045, 8.312999999999999, 8.335, 8.388, 8.437999999999999, 8.456, 8.227, 8.266, 8.277999999999999, 8.289, 8.299, 8.318, 8.332, 8.34, 8.349, 8.36, 8.363999999999999, 8.368, 8.282, 8.283999999999999]
time = range(1,85,1)   
x=int(0.7*len(data))
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*[time, data])))
df.columns = ['time', 'data']
# print df
x=int(0.7*len(df))
train = df[:x]
valid = df[x:]
models = []
names = []
tr_x_ax = []
va_x_ax = []
pr_x_ax = []
tr_y_ax = []
va_y_ax = []
pr_y_ax = []
time_model = []
models.append(('LR', LinearRegression()))

for name, model in models:
    x_train=df.iloc[:, 0][:x].values
    y_train=df.iloc[:, 1][:x].values
    x_valid=df.iloc[:, 0][x:].values
    y_valid=df.iloc[:, 1][x:].values

    model = LinearRegression()
    # poly = PolynomialFeatures(5)
    x_train= x_train.reshape(-1, 1)
    y_train= y_train.reshape(-1, 1)
    x_valid = x_valid.reshape(-1, 1)
    y_valid = y_valid.reshape(-1, 1)
    # model.fit(x_train,y_train)
    model.fit(x_train,y_train.ravel())
    # score = model.score(x_train,y_train.ravel())
    # print 'score', score
    preds = model.predict(x_valid)
    tr_x_ax.extend(train['data'])
    va_x_ax.extend(valid['data'])
    pr_x_ax.extend(preds)

    valid['Predictions'] = preds
    valid.index = df[x:].index
    train.index = df[:x].index
    plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    # plt.plot(train['data'],label='data')
    # plt.plot(valid[['Close', 'Predictions']])
    x = valid['data']
    # print x
    # plt.plot(valid['data'],label='validation')
    plt.plot(valid['Predictions'],label='Predictions before',color='orange')



y =range(0,58)
y1 =range(58,84)
for index, item in enumerate(pr_x_ax):
    if index >13:
        pr_x_ax[index] = pr_x_ax[13]
pr_x_ax = list([float(i) for i in pr_x_ax])
va_x_ax = list([float(i) for i in va_x_ax])
tr_x_ax = list([float(i) for i in tr_x_ax])
plt.plot(y,tr_x_ax,  label='train' , color='red',  linewidth=2)
plt.plot(y1,va_x_ax,  label='validation1' , color='blue',  linewidth=2)
plt.plot(y1,pr_x_ax,  label='Predictions after' , color='green',  linewidth=2)
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("data")
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

If you see this figure:

label: `Predictions before`, the model predicted it without any constraints (I don't need this result).

label: `Predictions after`, the model predicted it within a constraint but this is after the model predicted AND the all values are equal to last value at `index = 71 , item 8.56`.

I used  for loop `for index, item in enumerate(pr_x_ax):` in line:64, and the curve is line straight from time 71 to 85 sec as you see in order to show you how I need the model work.

Could I build the model give the same result instead of for loop???

[image: figure]

Please your suggestions

Comment: Could you make your question shorter and more to the point? I've read twice and I still don't get the question.

Comment: I made a short question.

Comment: @Algabri It looks like that turn to the right that you've drawn on green line can't be predicted at all given only training red line points. For such turns to be predictable you need some training points around that turn location. Otherwise right now by training points given model just thinks that all predictions should be approximated just with straight line without turns.

Comment: @Algabri In order to have good solution you need to randomly sample data for training and validation. Instead of doing `df[:x]` and `df[x:]` you need to put random `(x, y)` points to train set and random to validation set in needed proportions, like 70% to train and 30% to validation. Then your training should achieve correct green results.

Comment: @Algabri Also LinearRegression predicts data only with single straight line, it can't have turns, for piecewise linear approximation, as you want on green line, some more complex model should be used, I'll try to read docs to find such model.

Comment: What is a Constrained Linear Regression?

Comment: @Arty, thanks for your comments and suggestion, I am usually using a polynomial (n-degree) with linear regression models.  Here posting the code with only linear regression so that it will be easy.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov, Thanks for your question. Please see  https://towardsdatascience.com/constrained-linear-regression-aaf488296d93

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect that in your question by drawing green line you really expect trained model to predict linear horizontal turn to the right. But current trained model draws just straight orange line.

It is true for any trained model of any algorithm and type that in order to learn some unordinary change in behavior model needs to have at least some samples of that unordinary change. Or at least some hidden meaning in observed data should point to having such unordinary change.

In other words for your model to learn that right turn on green line a model should have points with that right turn in the training data set. But you take for training data just first (leftmost) 70% of data by `train = df[:int(0.7 * len(df))]` and that training data has no such right turns and this training data just looks close to one straight line.

So you need to re-sample your data into training and validation in a different way - take randomly 70% of samples from whole range of `X` and the rest goes to validation. So that in your training data samples that do right turn also included.

Second thing is that `LinearRegression` model always models predictions just with one single straight line, and this line can't have right turns. In order to have right turns you need some more complex model.

One way for a model to have a right turn is to be piece-wise-linear, i.e. having several joined straight lines. I didn't find ready-made piecewise linear models inside `sklearn`, only using other `pip` models. So I decided to implement my own simple class `PieceWiseLinearRegression` that uses `np.piecewise()` and `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()` in order to model piecewise linear function.

Next picture shows results of applying two mentioned things above, code goes afterwards, re-sampling dataset in a different way and modeling piece-wise-linear function. Your current linear model `LR` still makes a prediction using just one straight blue line, while my piecewise linear `PWLR2`, orange line, consists of two segments and correctly predicts right turn:

[image: img]

To see clearly just one `PWLR2` graph I did next picture too:

[image]

My class `PieceWiseLinearRegression` on creation of object accepts just one argument `n` - number of linear segments to be used for prediction. For picture above `n = 2` was used.

```
import sys, numpy as np, pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
np.random.seed(0)

class PieceWiseLinearRegression:
    @classmethod
    def nargs_func(cls, f, n):
        return eval('lambda ' + ', '.join([f'a{i}'for i in range(n)]) + ': f(' + ', '.join([f'a{i}'for i in range(n)]) + ')', locals())
        
    @classmethod
    def piecewise_linear(cls, n):
        condlist = lambda xs, xa: [(lambda x: (
            (xs[i] <= x if i > 0 else np.full_like(x, True, dtype = np.bool_)) &
            (x < xs[i + 1] if i < n - 1 else np.full_like(x, True, dtype = np.bool_))
        ))(xa) for i in range(n)]
        funclist = lambda xs, ys: [(lambda i: (
            lambda x: (
                (x - xs[i]) * (ys[i + 1] - ys[i]) / (
                    (xs[i + 1] - xs[i]) if abs(xs[i + 1] - xs[i]) > 10 ** -7 else 10 ** -7 * (-1, 1)[xs[i + 1] - xs[i] >= 0]
                ) + ys[i]
            )
        ))(j) for j in range(n)]
        def f(x, *pargs):
            assert len(pargs) == (n + 1) * 2, (n, pargs)
            xs, ys = pargs[0::2], pargs[1::2]
            xa = x.ravel().astype(np.float64)
            ya = np.piecewise(x = xa, condlist = condlist(xs, xa), funclist = funclist(xs, ys)).ravel()
            #print('xs', xs, 'ys', ys, 'xa', xa, 'ya', ya)
            return ya
        return cls.nargs_func(f, 1 + (n + 1) * 2)
        
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.f = self.piecewise_linear(self.n)

    def fit(self, x, y):
        from scipy import optimize
        self.p, self.e = optimize.curve_fit(self.f, x, y, p0 = [j for i in range(self.n + 1) for j in (np.amin(x) + i * (np.amax(x) - np.amin(x)) / self.n, 1)])
        #print('p', self.p)
        
    def predict(self, x):
        return self.f(x, *self.p)

data = [5.269, 5.346, 5.375, 5.482, 5.519, 5.57, 5.593999999999999, 5.627000000000001, 5.724, 5.818, 5.792999999999999, 5.817, 5.8389999999999995, 5.882000000000001, 5.92, 6.025, 6.064, 6.111000000000001, 6.1160000000000005, 6.138, 6.247000000000001, 6.279, 6.332000000000001, 6.3389999999999995, 6.3420000000000005, 6.412999999999999, 6.442, 6.519, 6.596, 6.603, 6.627999999999999, 6.76, 6.837000000000001, 6.781000000000001, 6.8260000000000005, 6.849, 6.875, 6.982, 7.018, 7.042000000000001, 7.068, 7.091, 7.204, 7.228, 7.261, 7.3420000000000005, 7.414, 7.44, 7.516, 7.542000000000001, 7.627000000000001, 7.667000000000001, 7.821000000000001, 7.792999999999999, 7.756, 7.871, 8.006, 8.078, 7.916, 7.974, 8.074, 8.119, 8.228, 7.976, 8.045, 8.312999999999999, 8.335, 8.388, 8.437999999999999, 8.456, 8.227, 8.266, 8.277999999999999, 8.289, 8.299, 8.318, 8.332, 8.34, 8.349, 8.36, 8.363999999999999, 8.368, 8.282, 8.283999999999999]
time = list(range(1, 85))
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(time, data)), columns = ['time', 'data'])

choose_train = np.random.uniform(size = (len(df),)) < 0.8
choose_valid = ~choose_train

x_all = df.iloc[:, 0].values
y_all = df.iloc[:, 1].values
x_train = df.iloc[:, 0][choose_train].values
y_train = df.iloc[:, 1][choose_train].values
x_valid = df.iloc[:, 0][choose_valid].values
y_valid = df.iloc[:, 1][choose_valid].values
x_all_lin = np.linspace(np.amin(x_all), np.amax(x_all), 500)

models = []
models.append(('LR', LinearRegression()))
models.append(('PWLR2', PieceWiseLinearRegression(2)))
        
for imodel, (name, model) in enumerate(models):
    model.fit(x_train[:, None], y_train)
    x_all_lin_pred = model.predict(x_all_lin[:, None])
    plt.plot(x_all_lin, x_all_lin_pred, label = f'pred {name}')

plt.plot(x_train, y_train, label='train')
plt.plot(x_valid, y_valid, label='valid')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It seems that will solve my issue. I am try to run your code in python 2, which expired in the first this year, but I am still using it because physical robot system require it (it needs to update the whole system). I got this error  **return eval('lambda ' + ', '.join(['a{i}' for i in range(n)]) + ': (' + ', '.join(['a{i}'for i in range(n)]) + ')', locals())**
  File "<string>", line 1
    lambda a{i}, a{i}, a{i}, a{i}, a{i}, a{i}, a{i}: (a{i}, a{i}, a{i}, a{i}, a{i}, a{i}, a{i})
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Algabri instead of `'a{i}'` in both places use `'a%s' % i`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help from my heart.
You really saved my time.